# Using try/except or if/else when copying files

Tags: python, file-io, try-catch, race-condition

I have two methods for copying a file, which one is the most pythonic/best version?

In working through an object-oriented textbook I've been told (paraphrasing here) that it's best to avoid checking and handle 'exceptional situations' when they arise. Is the way I've used `try`/`except` in the second version valid?

First version using `if`/`else`:

```
if os.path.exists(dest):
    print("\nCopying zipfile to {}".format(dest))
    shutil.copy(self.backup_zipfile_name, dest)
else:
    print("Cannot find {}.".format(dest))
```

Second version using `try`/`except`:

```
try:
    shutil.copy(self.back_zipfile_name, dest)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("{!r} could not be found".format(dest))
```

Comment: Second. First has a race condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely the second.

It's easy to think of your program steps as sequential actions where nothing else happens in between. But that's not really how computers (at least modern non-embedded ones) work.

In between you checking that the path exists and actually trying to write to it some other program could easily come along and delete it leading to an uncaught runtime exception. This is a common concurrency bug.

So always, always use `try/catch` (or in Python's case, `try/except`) when working with the filesystem, network, or any other external resource you don't completely control.

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) is a good resource with a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I think @Jared Smiths's response is more appropriate for that specific use case (accessing filesystem).

---

It's up to you as everyone said but here is what it says in python docs for your reference.

**LBYL**

> Look before you leap. This coding style explicitly tests for pre-conditions before making calls or lookups. This style contrasts with the EAFP approach and is characterized by the presence of many if statements.
>
> In a multi-threaded environment, the LBYL approach can risk introducing a race condition between “the looking” and “the leaping”. For example, the code, if key in mapping: return mapping[key] can fail if another thread removes key from mapping after the test, but before the lookup. This issue can be solved with locks or by using the EAFP approach.

**EAFP**

> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many other languages such as C.

https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html

Comment: Note that the race condition does not require multi-threading: any other program can manipulate the filesystem in the middle of your single-threaded sequential code. Or the driver could crash. Or any one of half a dozen other things could go wrong.

Comment: @JaredSmith, it will check in `if os.path.exists(dest)` . But the chance is only the time between 2 line of code execution.

Comment: @L_S it's enough. How many CPU cycles happen between those two steps? The Python interpreter converts your code to machine language for the computer to run, do you know the details of how the OS scheduler (for each different platform) doles out the CPU time to run it? Believe me, it's plenty of time for something to go wrong. This is a common anti-pattern in every language (not just Python).

Comment: @JaredSmith Its not plenty of time. Its plenty of computations. Next, Python interpreter is not converting to machine language one line by one when execution is going on. Also here only handling `FileNotFoundError`. which is enough in an `if else` .But say I am not a fan of `if else` but it depends on use cases.

Comment: @L_S the runtime details of the Python interpreter are irrelevant, this is a problem in every language including those that compile to native code. Any code running on top of an OS will have this issue. The only exception is code that *doesn't* run on top of an OS, i.e. a single-threaded embedded system.